# Inserting DATE TIMESTAMP Value to MySQL Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Using php I am inserting or updating the mysql database with create date or modified date using the variables

```
$datestring = "%Y:%m:%d %h:%i:%s";
$time = time();
$createdate= mdate($datestring, $time);
```

In this `$createdate` will be the variable I use to insert or update the table. But it's updating the wrong value. It's not the server time or localtime. Mostly it's 30 mins delay with the server's time.

Comment: What's timestamp format you're using? Mysql's timestamp field type format is YYYYMMDDHHIISS, not your monster string. And PHP's timestamp is merely what time() function returns.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function of PHP

```
$createdate= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: after some googling it looks like you're using CodeIgniter. You should have mentioned that in your question.

The format string you're using doesn't match MySQL's date format. You want to use:

```
$datestring = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s';
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning i am using codeigniter. Anyway thanks for pointing. :)

Answer (score 0):

use in  mysql query like DATE_FORMAT(purchaseDate, "%Y:%m:%d %h:%i:%s") function